# Glimpse misses 500 exception

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, glimpse

Glimpse is works fine when the site is pretty much working fine, but when there's a 500 is disappears.

[image: With Glimpse bar]

Compared to:

[image: No Glimpse bar]

You can see it here (as long as you log in as the user `glimpseuser`with password = `password`).

http://telemetrymvc.azurewebsites.net/Home/ThrowException

Unfortunately, the 500 are really quite important.

Is there some way for Glimpse to stay alive in the case of an exception?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, but you would have to handle the 500 error via MVC instead of relying on a static error page. Glimpse merely injects itself into the response HTML at runtime, and it can't do that with a static page. However, having 500 errors handled by MVC means you can end up in a redirect loop if there's an application-wide error: the applications redirects to the 500 handler which then also raises an exception causing it to redirect to the 500 handler, and so on.

If you want to risk it, then you'll need to add the `httpErrors` declaration to your Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="500" />
        <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/ServerError" />
    </httpErrors>
```

Then, you'd just need an `ErrorController` with a `ServerError` action, assuming you're using the default route.

However, Glimpse is really only meant for development, and even then, the yellow screens of death are more appropriate to be returned than something with Glimpse enabled. For production, you should be using some sort of alternative error logging application like Elmah or one of the many cloud-based options.

Comment: I agree that the yellow screen is more appropriate, we have other logging so it's not totally opaque.  Just would have been nice to have been able to keep the trace in the history for convenience.  **Very good point about the 500 handler!**